# Salesforce lightning input's element.set not working anymore after summer 18 release

Tags: salesforce-lightning

I am using below snippet to check for valid phone number format and then trying to set the formatted value to the current input element. But after summer 18 release I'm unable to set input with new formatted value.

TestApp

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">    
   <lightning:input type="text" label="Num" aura:id="ele" onchange=" 
    {!c.changeNum}" />
 </aura:application>
```

Controller:

```
({
    changeNum : function(component, event, helper) {
       helper.changeNum(component, event);
    }
})
```

Helper:

```
({
changeNum : function(component, event) {
    var element = event.getSource();
    var phonenumber = element.get("v.value");        
    if(phonenumber){                
            var updatedValue = phonenumber.replace(/-/g, "");
            if(/^\d{10}$/.test(updatedValue)){ 
                phonenumber = updatedValue.match(new RegExp('\\d{4}$|\\d{3}', 'g')).join("-");
            }
            else{
                var x = phonenumber.replace(/[^0-9._-]/g, "").replace(/ +/, " ");
                phonenumber = x;
               if(!/^[0-9-]+$/.test(phonenumber.slice(-1))){
                    phonenumber = phonenumber.slice(0, -1);
                }
            }
        }
    console.log(phonenumber);   
    element.set('v.value', phonenumber);
}
})
```

element.set is not able to update the formatted value. The lightning input element is still able to accept alphabets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can solve the issue by using **[Promise](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies)**

```
({
handleInputChange : function(component, event) {
    try {           
        var element = event.getSource();
        var inputValue = element.get("v.value");
        var formattedValue;
        var chkPattern = new Promise(
            function (resolve, reject) {
                if (inputValue) {
                    formattedValue = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9-]/g, "").replace(/ +/, " ");                        
                    resolve(formattedValue); // fulfilled
                } else {
                    var reason = new Error('kitten is not happy');
                    reject(reason); // reject
                }

            }
        );

        chkPattern.then(function (fulfilled) { 
            element.set('v.value', fulfilled);
        }).catch(function (error) {                
            console.log(error.message);                
        });
    } catch(e) {
        this.consoleLog(e.stack, true)
    }
}
```

})